# Using List of values against REGEXP or Like

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my present code

```
SELECT
   OBJECT_NAME  FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE ( OBJECT_NAME,
                  '^table1|^table2|^table3|..'
                  )
    AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```

I want to avoid writing too many text against Regexp , so i created table which has all the table_name within it.

so that i can do something like

```
SELECT
   OBJECT_NAME  FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME LIKE (SELECT NAME FROM TABLE_WITH_LIST)
 
    AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```

Any way i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course:

```
SELECT object_name
  FROM all_objects o,
       table_with_list x
 WHERE o.object_name LIKE x.name
   AND object_type = 'TABLE'
```

You will have to load table_with_list with patterns LIKE recognizes (with the % where you want it)

Comment: It may be better to place mask filtering in `exists` predicate to allow multiple matches without multiplication or source rows: `where ... and exists (select 'nothing' from table_with_list x where o.object_name like x.name)`

Comment: Yes, if table_with_list contents is not properly curated, that's probably warranted.